# Would cold temperatures affect a neutral safety switch? (Manual transmission)

Tags: starting, subaru, manual-transmission, legacy, cold

Trying to troubleshoot my 92 Subaru Legacy manual transmission starting issues.

Car wont crank/start most mornings, even if its only about 50 degrees F.

Replaced battery, starter, and alternator last year.

If the cars been in the sun for an hour it starts up either after a few key turns/pumps on the clutch, or right away.

**Would a failing neutral safety switch be affected by cool weather?**

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You can always test the NSS by bypassing it. Not good to leave it that way, but if you take the wires off and test, you could easily eliminate it as a culprit. I don't know if the Subie is open (no continuity between wires) or closed (continuity between the wires), so you'd have to test it both ways.

Comment: "Not good to leave it that way" Why not? Cars never used to have neutral safety switches. In fact, once I ran out of gas at an intersection and was able to put the car in gear and use the starter to safely get out of the intersection. So could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

Typically, if the NSS failed, the motor would not turn over.  Is that the situation here?

If you are able to start the car in gear with the clutch pedal depressed?  There's also a clutch safety switch.

Comment: Think the OP got it sorted or scrapped the car as the question was 25th April 2019...